# Put different git projects in the same folder

Tags: github

Locally I have several projects, typically books, in the same folder using the following folder tree.

```
  + books
  + book_1
     * .git
     * ... etc
  + book_2
     * .git
     * ... etc
```

Is it possible to keep this organization locally by using a master `books` repository in the github website ?

Comment: Have you looked into [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if you have a `books` repo in GitHub, in which you can push git [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (one for each project).
Each project is in its own GitHub repo.

It means locally that you have a books repo, in which you can do a

```
git submodule add -- https://<username>@github.com/<username>/book_1
git submodule add -- https://<username>@github.com/<username>/book_2
...
```

Then a simple `git clone --recursive https://<username>@github.com/<username>/books` will clone books and all submodules.

Comment: Thanks. Does this imply to have a github repository for each of my books on github ? I would like that on github only the big parent project `books` appears.

Comment: @projetmbc yes, that is what I meant with "Each project is in its own GitHub repo."

Comment: @projetmbc you could use two different GitHub account, one for books, one for all the books. That way, only books will appear in one of those GitHub accounts.

Comment: In that case, could I simply use my bitbucket account for each separated books ?

Comment: @projetmbc yes, you can use any repo hosting service for those submodule repos.

Comment: I have try in [this repo](https://github.com/projetmbc/books). Is it normal that I can't choose my submodules from the GUI of github ?

Comment: @projetmbc you could if it was another GitHub repo, but since it is a bitbucket one, I don't think you can.